# Why is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ a field?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

It seems to me that the hard part of this proof is multiplicative inverses. I know how to prove this by considering the multiplication of two arbitrary elements:

$$(a + b\sqrt{2})(a' + b'\sqrt{2}) = \dots$$

and seeing what values of $\{a', b'\}$ make the result equal to $1 + 0\sqrt{2}$. This is just solving a linear system, and at the end you get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a' &= -\frac{a}{2b^2 - a^2}\\
b' &= \frac{b}{2b^2 - a^2}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

It so happens that $2b^2 - a^2 \ne 0$ when $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, so the inverse always exists. Magic!

But it's just magic. Where did that come from? What is going on here? And can it be generalized to prove that these sorts of things are fields?

- $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$
- $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{q}] = \{a + b\sqrt{q} + c\sqrt[3]{q}^2\}$
- $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{q}, \sqrt{p}] = \{a + b\sqrt{q} + c\sqrt{p} + d\sqrt{pq}\}$

(I know that these are examples of "field extensions" from Wikipedia, but we've never talked about them in class. Also I imagine that $p$ and $q$ have to satisfy some conditions -- not being square is probably one.)

Comment: The question  is a bit strange.  $Q(\sqrt{2})$ is usually **defined** as "the smallest **field** containing all rational numbers and $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @user247327: Oh, interesting. It was defined for us as $\{a + b\sqrt{2} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and we were asked to prove that it was a field.

Comment: @user247327: Note that there's a difference between $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$. The latter is a field by definition; the former consists of all elements of the form $p(\sqrt2)$ where $p$ is some polynomial with rational coefficients. That is not automatically a field, though in the particular case of $\sqrt2$ it is.

Comment: It is fairly natural to study $\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}}$ by multiplying top and bottom by $a-b\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Nice! We still need that $a^2 - 2b^2 \ne 0$, right? So in order to apply that to the others, I guess I would need to know the conjugate of some arbitrary $a + b\sqrt[3]{q} + c\sqrt[3]{q}^2$?

Comment: Note that the inverse of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ in this field is the same as the inverse of that quantity regarded as an element of the field $\mathbb R$:$$\frac1{a+b\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a-b\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2}$$ $$=\left(\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}\right)+\left(\frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\right)\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$$

Comment: @Eli Rose: There is a proof for that.  It goes back to they Pythagoreans.  And there is a story that Pythagoras executed a man for leaking the proof.

Comment: @EliRose: Yes, but if $a^2-2b^2=0$, then $a^2=2b^2$ and so unless $b=0$ we have $(a/b)^2=2$, which is impossible because $\sqrt2$ is known to be irrational. And if $b=0$, then $a$ must also be $0$, and then $a+b\sqrt2$ is not supposed to be invertible in the first place!

Comment: Regarding your question about the the conjugate of the cube root expression, see footnote 1 on the first page the following old handout of mine, [Exotic Group Examples](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2143964-7218194-629524/group-examples.pdf).

Comment: To give a slightly different suggestion than Dave Renfro's handout, you can act on the cube root extension with all Galois group elements (there are a total of 6) to mimic finding the inverse of the quadratic extension. However, yet another way to approach the problem is by using the extended Euclidean algorithm as in the last example on this handout of mine:  http://mathsci2.appstate.edu/~cookwj/courses/math4010-spring2016/math4010-spring2016-factorization_theory.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is much more general: consider multiplication by $a +b\sqrt2$ in the $\mathbf Q$-vector space $\mathbf Q[\sqrt2]$. If is non-zero, it is an injective endomorphism of this space. As we're in finite dimension, an injective endomorphism is surjective. Hence $1$ is attained, i.e. there exists $a'+b'\sqrt2\in\mathbf Q[\sqrt2]$ such that $$(a +b\sqrt2)(a'+b'\sqrt2)=1.$$

The most general result is this:

> Let $A\hookrightarrow B$ an injective ring homomorphism. Suppose $A,
>  B$ are integral domains, and  $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.
>   Then $B$ is a field if and only if $A$ is a field.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for! Just to make sure -- I'm unfamiliar with the term "$\mathbf{Q}$-vector space", does that mean "the vector space which uses $\mathbf{Q}$ as its field of scalars"? So this vector space, $\mathbf{Q}$, would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^2$?

Comment: That's right. It has dimension $2$ over $\mathbf Q$ and the isomorphism maps $a+b\sqrt 2 $ to $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the answer you want, but here goes...

We call an element *algebraic* over a field (I'll stick to working over $\mathbb{Q}$) if it is the root of a non-zero polynomial over that field.

Say $\alpha$ is algebraic. If we take the set $I = \{ f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \;|\; f(\alpha)=0 \}$ (all polynomials with $\alpha$ as a root), $I$ forms an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Now $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain (PID) so $I$ has a generator, say $I=(p(x))$ (i.e.  everything in $I$ turns out to be a multiple of $p(x)$). Let's assume that $p(x)$ is monic (has a leading coefficient $1$).

$p(x)$ is then called the *minimal polynomial* of $\alpha$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$). This is the polynomial of least degree which has $\alpha$ as a root. Also, because of minimality it turns out that $p(x)$ is *irreducible*.

**For example:** $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is algebraic (over $\mathbb{Q}$) with minimal polynomial $x^3-2$. So any polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ which has $\sqrt[3]{2}$ as a root must be divisible by $x^3-2$.

Ok. Some ring theory: Irreducible polynomials generate *maximal* ideals. In other words, if $J$ is an ideal and $I \subseteq J \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $J=I$ or $J=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (there's nothing between $I$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$). Quotients by maximal ideals yield fields. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ is a field.

What does this have to do with $\alpha$?

Consider the evaluation homomorphism: $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\varphi(f(x))=f(\alpha)$ (i.e. plug in $\alpha$). By definition, the image of $\varphi$ is $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ (i.e. polynomials with $\alpha$ plugged in). The kernel of $\varphi$ is the set of all $f(x)$ such that $\varphi(f(x))=f(\alpha)=0$. This is exactly $I=(p(x))$! By the first isomorphism theorem: $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x)) \cong \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. Since we know that the quotient is a field, $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a field.

Now what if $\alpha$ is transcendental (i.e. not algebraic)? Then there is no non-zero polynomial with $\alpha$ as a root. This means that the kernel is trivial. In that case $\mathbb{Q}[x] \cong \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. Now $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is *not* a field. So for transcendental elements, $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] \not= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (parentheses thing = smallest field containing thing).

Now why does the magic trick work for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$?

Basically Galois theory.

An image of an element under a Galois automorphism us called a *conjugate* (generalizing the complex conjugate). For $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ you have 2 automorphisms: (1) The identity $a+b\sqrt{2} \mapsto a+b\sqrt{2}$ and (2) The other one $a+b\sqrt{2} \mapsto a-b\sqrt{2}$ (i.e. send $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$).

A product of an element and all of its conjugates yields an element of the *base field* so $(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})$ must be rational. Using this you can then rig up the "magic trick" to rationalize the inverse of an element.

Answer (score 1):

$(a+b\sqrt2)(a-b\sqrt2) = a^2 - 2b^2$

If $a^2 - 2b^2 \ne 0, \frac{a}{a^2-2b^2} - \frac{b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt2$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a+b\sqrt2$

If $a^2 - 2b^2 = 0$ then $a$ or $b$ is irrational. (Or $a$ = $b$ = $0$)

Comment: Thanks for the response! So, I understand that this works for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$: my question is why, and can it be generalized?

Comment: You can read about this in Wikipedia: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension]

Comment: "If $a^2-2b^2 = 0$, then $a$ or $b$ is irrational." False. Both being $0$ work (tho there's no multiplicative inverse in that case).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blindly solving the linear system, you can also observe that $(a+b\sqrt2)(a-b\sqrt 2) = a^2-2b^2$, where the right-hand side is rational and can be divided away -- so $$\frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a^2-2b^2} = \frac{a}{a^2-2b^2} + \frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt2$$ must be an inverse of $a+b\sqrt 2$.

This principle works for $\mathbb Q[\sqrt D]$ in general (so-called *quadratic field*). With some modifications it can also be used for for $\mathbb Q[\sqrt D,\sqrt E]$ (eliminate the square roots one at a time), but heavier methods are needed $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]D]$.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the real question here is *why* all nontrivial solutions of $a^2-2b^2=0$ are irrational.

Assume $b\neq 0$. Then we get $\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{2}$. But the RHS is irrational, so the LHS must have at least one irrational term.

Assume $b=0$. Then $a=0$

This proof works for the same problem where we replace $\sqrt{2}$ with $\sqrt{D}$ for any non-square $D$.

Comment: And if $D$ is square, then of course $\mathbb Q[\sqrt D]=\mathbb Q$, which we already know is a field ...

Answer (score 0):

From the edit:

> And can it be generalized to prove that these sorts of things are fields?

The "magic" that is going on to compute inverses is actually not necessary to prove these things are fields, i.e. that when complex numbers $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_m$ are roots of (rational coefficient) polynomials then the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\cdots,x_m]$ (the set of all polynomial expressions in $x_1,\cdots,x_m$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{Q}$) is a closed under the operations of not just addition and multiplication but division as well. Firstly, one can induct, since we can write $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\cdots,x_m]=\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\cdots,x_{m-1}][x_m]$. That is, we must show that when $K$ is some field comprised of complex numbers and $x$ is an algebraic number, then $K[x]$ is also a field. To do this, we just need some linear algebra.

Use the fact that $x$ is a root of a polynomial to determine that $K[x]$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$. Observe there are no zero divisors, i.e. the zero product property $ab=0\Rightarrow a=0$ or $b=0$ holds. Then pick any nonzero element $a\in K[x]$, and consider the function $f(x)=ax$ which is "multiplication-by-$a$." This is a linear map, and by the zero product property its kernel is trivial, hence it is a bijection (as $K[x]$ is finite-dimensional), which means there exists a $b$ for which $f(b)=1$, i.e. $ab=1$. This shows all nonzero elements are invertible in $K[x]$.

From the comments:

> So in order to apply that to the others, I guess I would need to know the conjugate of some arbitrary $a + b\sqrt[3]{q} + c\sqrt[3]{q}^2$?

Indeed, computing inverses in such contexts amounts to "rationalizing the denominator," which itself involves computing conjugates. However when our algebraic numbers are roots of polynomials beyond degree two, there will be more than one conjugate! What is a conjugate of an algebraic number anyway?

If $x$ is the root of some polynomial, then there is a unique monic polynomial of minimal degree having $x$ as a root, and this is termed the *minimal* polynomial of $x$. The conjugates of $x$ are precisely the other roots of this minimal polynomial. The *norm* of $x$ will be the product of all these conjugates, which will be rational since it is plus or minus the constant coefficient of the minimal polynomial. Thus, to compute $1/x$, simply multiply the top and bottom by all of $x$'s conjugates.

(To be clear: I am speaking of $x$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, and the norm in the relative extension $\mathbb{Q}(x)/\mathbb{Q}$.)

This broaches the subject of [*Galois theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory). A **number field** is (essentially) any collection of complex numbers which is closed under the usual arithmetic operations ($+,-,\times,/$) and is a finite-dimensional vector space over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, you've seen $K=\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{2}$ is such a number field.

A **symmetry** of a number field (relative to $\mathbb{Q}$ anyway) is a relabelling of its elements, i.e. a function $f:K\to K$, which preserves the truth of all equations upon relabelling. For example, the "conjugation" map $a+b\sqrt{2}\mapsto a-b\sqrt{2}$ is a relabelling of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{2}$ (treat $a+b\sqrt{2}$ as a single number), and this relabelling turns the true equation $(1+\sqrt{2})^2=3+2\sqrt{2}$ into $(1-\sqrt{2})^2=3-2\sqrt{2}$, which is another true equation. Since all our equations are essentially polynomial expressions built from the arithmetic operations, it suffices to check such a function preserves the arithmetic operations, i.e. that it satisfies the two properties $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.

The symmetry group of a number field is its **Galois group** $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ defined by

$$\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})=\left\{f:K\to K~\mathrm{such~that}~ \begin{array}{c} f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b) \\ f(ab)=f(a)f(b) \end{array}~\mathrm{for~all~}a,b\in K\right\}. $$

(I am avoiding discussing the important caveat that some extensions are not "Galois," i.e. the number of symmetries is less than it what it's supposed to be, which is the dimension of $K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.)

If $K=\mathbb{Q}(x)$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})=\{\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n\}$ then the symmetries $\sigma_i$ shuffle the roots of polynomials, hence they restrict to permutations on $x$'s conjugates, and in particular the set of conjugates is precisely the "orbit" $\{\sigma_1(x),\cdots,\sigma_n(x)\}$!

Determining what the symmetries in a Galois group are is in general a very difficult problem. Sometimes you need a number system a little bigger than $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ in order to get all of $x$'s conjugates (the "Galois closure"). For instance, there are no nontrivial symmetries of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\subset\mathbb{R}$, but if you allow a complex number into the mix (a cube root of unity $\omega=\cos(2\pi/3)+i\sin(2\pi/3)$), then the conjugates of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ are $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}$, and more generally the conjugates of $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$ are

$$ a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}, \quad a+b\omega\sqrt[3]{2}+c\omega^2\sqrt[3]{4}, \quad a+b\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}+c\omega\sqrt[3]{4}. $$